# How to delete empty select option?

Tags: html, firefox

quick question how can i delete or hide an empty select option?

```
<select id="ho" size="1" style="width: 143px;">
             <option>Option 1</option>
             <option>Option 2<option>
</select>
```

Like you can see there are only 2 options, but there is an 3 the empty one how can I delete or hide the 3 option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to close the second option tag. This should work:

```html
<select id="ho" size="1" style="width: 143px;">
     <option>Option 1</option>
     <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```